# Auto create MySQL stored procedures in Grails application

Tags: mysql, grails, stored-procedures, grails-2.0

In my Grails application I am using MySQL. For certain database processing heavy functionalities, I need some stored procedures. In my development environment, because of the changing schemas, configuration and static data, I wish to rebuild the database at each startup (and because it is very fast). My stored procedures are stored in native SQL files that are ready to run against the database.

What is the best way of integrating the creation of these procedures in a Grails application? What I was thinking about is to make it part of my Bootstrap process, locating those files and querying them against the datasource I have. However, I was wondering if there was any best practice regarding this issue, as my idea seems to be a bit raw.

Comment: Most people would use database migrations for these sort of things

Comment: @Aston Yes, the plugin.

Comment: So, you mean like I install the plugin, create an SQL changelog file containing my stored procedures and I turn on the auto update?